# Remotely edit excel files

Tags: excel, remote-access, vba

I have a team sitting in different offices, who are all hooked to the company server. Each uses an excel file for carrying out some calculations, which has some parameter values encoded in one of the sheets. Now, whenever the parameter values change, I have to update the excel file and circulate the new file to everyone. Is there a way I could do this remotely? i.e. the excel files connect to some master file in the server to get the parameter values, and whenever the master file is updated, all excel files get the new parameter values automatically?

I have some basic knowledge of vba and I hope there is a simple solution. Otherwise I have to get a web-browser launched service which will cost a lot of time and money.

Comment: The basic problem that they need to open the file to refresh the values, so after you  publish changes wherever you need to notify them, and they need to open the file to get the results. In my company we use sharepoint list for this and it works well.

Comment: Thanks :) I am actually looking for a solution where the end users are not required to do anything (eg opening the master file and refreshing the value). Such a process always carries a risk that the users will make a mistake. I will check if we have sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is unclear.

Does each team member work with an Excel file on their hard drive? And these files are duplicates? Or do you have individual files stored on the server?

Who would change the parameter values? Is it done by one team member, or can anyone change them? If anyone can change them, what happens when two team members make different changes? This scenario is getting into version control software or database territory.

If only one person updates parameter values, that makes things easier. You simply need a way (Sharepoint, email, master parameter file on the server) to distribute updates.

Also, I'm not sure this is a VBA question.

Comment: The team members have identical excel files in their hard drives. I will be the only person making the changes - nobody in the team has access to the parameters. Right now I am using emails - whenever there is an update I change the version of the excel file and circulate. This, however, leaves the process prone to human error if the incorrect version is used. I was wondering if there is a way no action is required from the end-users? i.e. the excel file itself will connect to the master file and update the values every time?